# Using a config file to allocate array at compile time in c++

Tags: c++, g++, software-design

I am a bit new to c++ and want to learn more by trying a specific project. This project is somewhat bigger project where I want to test the dependence of some numerical method "function" with respect to parameters like array size and what not. I figured the best way to organize my code would be to create

1. A file implementing the functions I want to use

```
// implement.h
#include <cmath>

struct input_params{
    int input_array_size;
    // other parameters
}

void function(float* , float* , input_params);
```

```
// implement.cpp
#include <cmath>
#include "implement.h"

void function(float *input, float *output, input_params args){
    // do stuff
}
```

2. A config file specifying what my input_params will contain (with a corresponding header file)

```
#include "config.h"
input_params args;
```

```
#include "implement.h"
#include "config.h"

input_params args;
args.input_array_size = 100; // something I would change before compile time
```

3. A script that will actually run the code

```
#include <cmath>
#include "implement.h"
#include "config.h"

// float *input = new [arg.input_array_size];
float input[arg.input_array_size]; // I want to make this stack-allocated for performance reasons

// float *output = new [arg.output_array_size];
float output[arg.output_array_size]; 

function(input, output, args);
```

My questions are as follows:

1. How should I compile the code using g++?
2. How do compile my "config" file so that my parameters are known at compile time?
3. Is there a better, alternative way of actually doing this?

Comment: You can instead try vectors

Answer (score 1):

The simplest approach would be to make your configuration file create macros:

```
// config.h
#define ARG_INPUT_SIZE 100
#define ARG_OUTPUT_SIZE 300
```

```
// some_other_file.c
#include "config.h"

float input[ARG_INPUT_SIZE];
float output[ARG_OUTPUT_SIZE];
```

It's pretty unlikely that allocating this in the bss vs the heap is actually going to be meaningfully important to any performance metrics.

Comment: Why macros, though? Why not constant integer variables? (Or, const/constexpr `input_params`)

Answer (score 0):

> 3. *"Is there a better, alternative way of actually doing this?"*

Of course there is. Just use a [`std::vector<float>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) for the input / output parameters. You can adapt the necessary size of them dynamically as needed.

If you still want fixed sizes, and do that at compile time you can use [`std::array<float,MY_SIZE>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) and define the size you want using the `-D` command line option of g++:

```
g++ -D MY_SIZE=100 ...
```

`std::vector` and `std::array` are a lot easier to deal with than raw c-style arrays or pointers.

Example code:

```
#include <array>

using inarray_t = std::array<float,MY_INPUT_SIZE>;
using outarray_t  = std::array<float,MY_OUTPUT_SIZE>;

// Change the signature of your function
void function(inarray_t&, outarray_t& , input_params);

// ...

int main() {
    // ...
    inarray_t input; // this is stack-allocated for performance reasons
    outarray_t output; // this is stack-allocated for performance reasons

    // ...
}
```

Take care that the stack allocations don't exceed the stack size limitations, these aren't that big usually, and you can end up with stack overflow (no pun intended) very quickly.